# How to reset allwinner kitkat 4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, locked-out

I have forgotten the lock code for my kitkat 4.4. Is there a way to hard reset it back to factory? I only have a power button and a volume button. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I've added the [tag:locked-out] tag to your question. You might like to start by clicking through to the existing questions in that tag, and try the steps that have worked for other people.

Comment: While I concur with @DanHulme I'd suggest starting at the [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) where we've already summed up some core information. If that didn't solve your issue, please continue as Dan suggested.

Answer (score 1):

AllWinner devices (devices powered by a AllWinner CPU) don't have a recovery menu from which to perform a  factory reset.

In order to reset your device, you will need to know which CPU is inside. AllWinner CPU have number such as A10, A13, A23, A33, etc. Such information can be found out from the device's specifications from the internet or manually by opening the device and then locate the CPU.

So, when you get all the information about the CPU, you will need to find the ROM/firmware for that device then flash it to the device using a tool called PhoenixSuit or LiveSuit (both are similar).

The flashing process is quite simple. Go **[here](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f906/phoenixusbpro-flashing-tutorial-allwinner-a23-cpu-devices-1900745/)** for a tutorial on how to use PhoenixSuit for flashing a AllWinner device (A23 in the example).

Comment: Did you read the question? Seems not.  OP said they've forgotten their lock code hence they're locked out! I don't think those apps would be useful...

Comment: Sorry. You are right ! +1